# How to Display Output in Richtextbox in a Loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a richtextbox to display the output of a loop at the click of a button. How do I do this? This is the section of code in question

```
Private Sub calculate_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculate_btn.Click
    interest = principal = ((1 + roi / compoundFreq) ^ (compoundFreq * numbryears) - 1)
    numbryears = endyear - startyear

    Dim output_txt As Integer
    For thisyear = startyear To endyear
        output_txt += thisyear
    Next thisyear

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want all the intermediate values of `output_txt` displayed in the `RichTextbox`, probably on separate lines?  Just put all the values together into a single `String` and display that. There are better ways and you can research them but surely you can concatenate to an existing `String` inside that loop if you can add to an existing `Integer`.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes, output_txt is the name given to the richtextbox I would like the output to be displayed in. And yes I'd like all the values to be displayed on separate lines if possible.

Comment: But you clearly state that out_txt is an Integer not a RichTextBox. On every iteration of your loop you are overwriting the value of the Integer out_txt.

Comment: Is this a typo `interest = principal =`?

Comment: Assume `Dim startyear = 2011`  `Dim endyear = 2018` Then your loop would produce 2011
4023
6036
8050
10065
12081
14098
16116

Comment: Yes it is a typo, it's supposed to be *

Comment: Ideally it would display like "Interest at the end of 2018 = $30.00"